# How to sort geolocations by distance?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, geolocation

I have a XML file with info about a bus stops (e.g. route number, coordinates **(lat, lon)** of bus stop, etc.). 
I have a task: **Print the longest route using coordinates**. 
In general I understand the algorithm:

1. Do the matches between route number and vector of its coordinates.
2. Get length of each route *(it's a broken line, let's say it's straight in order to make code simpler, it doesn't matter)*, where the vertex is a bus stop with its coordinates.
3. Find the max and print it.

**The problem is**: the data is unsorted, so if I try to get distance between two points (**i** and **i + 1** for instance) the result will be wrong because geographically between these 2 points there're other points (there're somewhere further in the array)  and they will be ignored -> length size will be wrong too. 
Is there any ways to fix it?

Here is what I managed to do:

```
 double getDistance(double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2) {
    double la1 = lat1 * M_PI / 180.0;
    double la2 = lat2 * M_PI / 180.0;

    // Haversine
    double dlat = (lat2 - lat1) * M_PI / 180.0;
    double dlong = (long2 - long1) * M_PI / 180.0;

    double ans = (sin(dlat / 2) * sin(dlat / 2)) +
                 cos(la1) * cos(la2) * sin(dlong / 2) * sin(dlong / 2);

    double c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(ans), sqrt(1 - ans));
    double R = 6371;
    double d = R * c; // in metres

    return d;
}
void getLongestRoute(vector<elementXML> transport, string transportName) {
    // key - routeNumber, value - vector of coordinates 
    map<string, vector<pair<double, double>>> routesData;

    // getting each route
    for (int i = 0; i < transport.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < transport.at(i).getRoutes().size(); j++) {
            routesData[transport.at(i).getRoutes().at(j)].push_back(transport.at(i).getCoordinates());
        }
    }

    double maxLength = 0.0;
    string max = "";
    double length = 0.0;
    for (const auto &routes : routesData) {
        for (int i = 0; i < routes.second.size() - 1; i++) {
            length += getDistance(routes.second.at(i).first, routes.second.at(i).second,
                                  routes.second.at(i + 1).first, routes.second.at(i + 1).second);
        }
        if (length > maxLength) {
            maxLength = length;
            max = routes.first;
        }
        length = 0;
    }
    cout << "Longest route for " << transportName << " - " << "#" << max << ", length - "
         << round(maxLength) << " km" << endl;
}
```

Example of what I get from console:

> Longest route for BUS - #487, length - 1050 km  // ~90 km expected

It will be amazing if I get any help. Thanks.

Comment: The problem does not make sense as the busses can not fly. Instead these travel (by rather non-straight routes) from stop to stop. So it is generally solved as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem

Comment: You said the info is unsorted, so how do you know what the actual route is, if it's not simple [0] -> [1] -> [2] etc?

Comment: This is not a coding problem but an algorithm problem. My advice is to draw a diagram with a few example points, write out your best-guess algorithm to solve it (on paper, or in notepad++ if you prefer). If your algorithm requires a complicated step, break that out into its own algorithm. Don't even attempt to write a single line of code until you understand the algorithm. This algorithm also includes what your input data is. If you don't even understand what your input data is, you MUST understand that first BEFORE moving on to the next step.

Comment: @ÖöTiib oh, the idea of using graphs is interesting, I will try, thanks. And yeah, I meant that buses travel from stop to stop, right

Comment: @JosephLarson that's the whole point)

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand what you are trying to do, but generally speaking, there is [no known efficient solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) to finding the [longest path between two points in a graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem)

Comment: @amit I checked my xml file and realised that it was filled incorrectly, there are some bus stops that contain multiple values for route number. If I ignore them, everything should be fine.

Comment: Why would you ignore that multiple busses can stop at the same bus stop? can't line A and B have some common stops so people can change bus?

Comment: @sashafromlibertalia Well, in this case either this is happening by chance (broken clock is right twice a day), or indeed I do not properly understand the problem and it's not classic longest path problem.

Comment: @Surt because it's really hard to know which info I should ignore and which not. I don't know how to describe it, but the data in this file is really confusing. In fact, it's my university homework and I think it will be okay to print just only route number (my code finds it properly)

Comment: Could you give an example of the input data, 3 first stops maybe?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jdPPurff @Surt

Comment: I would read it as if 487 is named twice, then it means the bus stops there on both directions it runs from A to B back and forth as opposed to a circular line, which some of the others might be. On the other hand it doesn't appear that the file says anything about the order of stops the bus has.

Comment: @Surt yeah, that't the problem. I've decided to stop losing my time and do another task, I think it's a problem of this file ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you change the problem slightly, it makes sense. "Print the longest shortest-route". That is, find the shortest possible route for each, then print the longest one. Then it's a simple shortest route problem.